# What is the meaning of "tease back"?

Tags: word-usage

I read a sentence in The Hindu which was:

> Still, with military tensions with Pakistan on the boil, and little fiscal leeway to tease back momentum through increased spending,.....

What does "tease back" mean here?

Comment: I'm having trouble making sense of any of this with any sense of the word *tease*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sentence probably relates indirectly to meaning 2 of **tease** in the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tease):

> 2. Gently pull or comb (tangled wool, hair, etc.) into separate strands

This meaning of **tease** can also be used metaphorically- to gently rearrange something in a situation where using more strength would probably make the situation worse.

In this sentence, momentum probably relates to economic growth, so "tease back momentum" means to gently encourage economic growth.